# Show the following is a JordanRegion

Tags: analysis

I have to show that the open ball $B_r(b)$ is a Jordan Region for every $a\in R^n$. So I need to show that the boundary $\delta B_r$ is zero. I have already shown that $\delta B_r(b)= \{x:||x-b||=r\}$. So how do I show it is zero?

Comment: It makes no sense to say that a set "is zero". Well, a circle certainly **looks** like zero, still, I would not say that it **is** zero.

Comment: I think you need to specify the measure and ball is what space

Comment: I corrected it @JohnZHANG it is in $R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Lebesgue measure is translation invariant. Hence it suffices to show $|\partial B_r(0)|=0$

Then consider $|\partial B_r(0)|\le |\{x|r-\delta\le\|x\|<r+\delta\}|=|B_{r+\delta}(0)\setminus B_{r-\delta}(0)|=|B_{r+\delta}(0)|- |B_{r-\delta}(0)|\to0$ as $\delta \to 0$

Comment: I was thinking that we could show that it is a Jordan region with volume zero if we showed that $\delta B_{r} (b)$ < $\epsilon$. @JohnZHANG

Comment: @user123 I think the proof is similar to the proof I wrote above, just choose small enough $\delta$..